# How to use for loop variable to use as part of csv file names for writing many csv files?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

In R, I am working on web-scraping (with rvest) hockey draft history pages and I created a for loop to loop through 40 webpages, grab the table and then I want to write each one to a separate csv file.  In my loop I am looping through years and pasting them with a url to go to each url.  How can I use the year used in each url to also be the csv files name (ex. 1979.csv, 1980.csv, ...).

When I try to use:

```
write_csv(export, path = paste0("~/hockey_draft/csv/1979.csv"))
```

This gives me one csv file with the 1979.csv name.  I believe I have to use `paste0()` and use the i from the for loop but it doesn't seem to work.

## Code

```
library(tidyverse)

library(rvest)

year <- list(1979:2018)

new_list <- NULL
```

### For loop:

```
for (i in year) {
    new_list <- c(new_list, paste("https://www.hockey-reference.com/draft/NHL_",i,"_entry.html", sep = ""))

    for (y in new_list) {
        url <- as.character(y)
        export <- url %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[[1]] %>% html_table()

        # Write to csv file
        write_csv(export, path = paste0("~/hockey_draft/csv/",i,".csv"))
    }
}
```

I am looking to get 40 csv files from 1979 through 2018.

Comment: You don't need `list` year, you just want regular vectors. (Use lists to store things that don't fit in vectors, like a list of data frames or a list of matrices. Or use lists to store things of different shapes, like a list of a value, a data frame, and a character vector). Change year to `year <- 1979:2019` so it's just a normal numeric vector. `new_list` should be a character vector, and it's better to initialize it to the right length, `new_list <- character(0)`.

Comment: are you sure you got the write .csv function in the right for loop bracktes?

Comment: You also don't need an inner loop - I think. You want to create 1 csv per year, so you need 1 loop over the years. With an inner loop, you're creating 1 csv for each `new_list` item every year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `list` in this case. Also you can create all urls once without a loop using the function `paste`. Here is a way to do what you want:

```
library(rvest)

year <- 1979:2018
urls <- paste0("https://www.hockey-reference.com/draft/NHL_", year, "_entry.html")

for (i in 1:length(urls)){
  export <- urls[i] %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[[1]] %>% html_table()
  write.csv(x = export, file = paste0("~/hockey_draft/csv/", year[i],".csv"))
}
```

Hope it works.